# What is the approximate minimum coding rate for NLP datasets?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, information-theory

I just realized that it is actually practical to use information theory to compute the maximum viable compression for datasets & that it is easiest to compute for discrete datasets. This makes me wonder what the minimum coding rate (i.e. minimum required bit representation) for well known NLP datasets is? Also approximately how close to this minimum coding rate do modern transformers achieve in the embedding space?